# Guestfish - libguestfs copy-out to a Remote VM

Tags: kvm-virtualization, qemu, luks

I have a need to move a number of files from a snapshot of a LUKS encrypted virtual machine (CentOS) to another one on a different hypervisor. I can mount the partition in  the guestfish interactive shell and use copy-out to move the files to a local directory, but I'd like to find a way to do the move in fewer steps than:

copy-out to local > rsync to remote hypervisor > copy-in to remote VM

Has anyone done this by piping the output of copy out or something? Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Thanks,
Bob

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tar-out` to get a tar file (or `virt-tar-out` which is the equivalent command).  This can be piped into ssh to copy it across.  I guess that reduces the complexity by one step.  Something like:

```
virt-tar-out -a disk.img / - | ssh remote "cat > /tmp/remote.tar"
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it might do what I need - like you say, it reduces complexity, which should mean I can get it done faster which is my main concern.